# Mysterious protractor test failure when using custom util

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing

I want my tests to work no matter the order they are run in. Therefore I have created a util that logs in the test user if not already logged in. But it seems that when I am using the util that protractor misbehaves. Please read on. The util looks like this:

```
export class E2EUtils {
  loginAndGoTo(url: string) {
    return browser.get(url).then(() => {
      return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(
        (currentUrl) => {
          if (currentUrl.indexOf('/login') !== -1) {
            element(by.css('[name=email]')).sendKeys('user@email.com');
            element(by.css('[name=password]')).sendKeys('secret');
            element(by.css('login form button')).click();
          }
          expect(browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch('.*' + url + '$');
        }, (error) => {
          console.error('error in E2EUtil.loginAndGoTo', error);
        });
    });
  };
}
```

The test that uses the util

```
import { E2EUtils } from '../e2e-utils.e2e-spec';
let utils = new E2EUtils();

describe('Home', () => {
  it('should show right profile', (done) => {
    utils.loginAndGoTo('home/user').then(() => {
      expect(element(by.css('home p')).getText()).toContain('user');
      done();
    }, (e) => { console.error('error in home.component.e2e-spec.ts', e); });
  });
});
```

And it does not work. It hangs and eventually gives the error:

```
Failed: Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 11 seconds. Please see https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md
While waiting for element with locator - Locator: By(css selector, home p)
```

However. This 'identical test works'. Only difference is that I am not using the util.

```
  it('should show right profile-OLD', () => {
    browser.get('/home/user');
    element(by.css('[name=email]')).sendKeys('user@email.com');
    element(by.css('[name=password]')).sendKeys('secret');
    element(by.css('login form button')).click();
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch('.*home/user$');
    expect(element(by.css('home p')).getText()).toContain('user');
  });
```

I have also used the Element Explorer and tried the element locator myself and it only works when not using the util. Even though the correct page is visible. So it would seem that the util sets protractor in a weird state. On a side note, I could not use `browser.getCurrentUrl()` in the util method and instead had to user `browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()`. However, `browser.getCurrentUrl()` works in tests that does not use the util.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So I have found a workaround. If I add `ignoreSynchronization` and `sleep` for a while I can make the test pass. Like so:

```
it('should show right profile', (done) => {
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;                                 <--
  utils.loginAndGoTo('home/user').then(() => {
    sleep(1000);                                                        <--
    expect(element(by.css('home p')).getText()).toContain('user');
    done();
  }, (e) => { console.error('error in home.component.e2e-spec.ts', e); });
});
```

I can't figure out why this makes it work though. Somehow my util method (which is asynchronous) makes protractor believe it has to wait for angular? Additionally I can now use `browser.getCurrentUrl` instead of `browser.driver.getCurrentUrl`. Here is what the documentation for `ignoreSynchronization` says

```
/**
   * If true, Protractor will not attempt to synchronize with the page before
   * performing actions. This can be harmful because Protractor will not wait
   * until $timeouts and $http calls have been processed, which can cause
   * tests to become flaky. This should be used only when necessary, such as
   * when a page continuously polls an API using $timeout.
   *
   * @type {boolean}
   */
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution isn't good enough as it requires a lot of sleeps